# Add bookmark to Safari on iPhone when an application is installed?

Tags: iphone, safari

I'd like to add a bookmark to a users Mobile Safari bookmarks when they install my iPhone application.

I don't want the user to have to do it manually, i'd like my iphone app to install the bookmark (actually a javascript based bookmark, e.g. `javascript:`)

Does anyone know of anyway to do this?

Comment: Any updates or new api's from apple to add a bookmark from third party app?

Comment: I haven't had any need for this, but I googled, and the closest I see these days is [you can add an item to Safari's reading list](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14071270/how-to-add-an-url-to-safaris-reading-list-in-ios). Maybe that'll work for you ?

Comment: Yeah, thats the reading list. Thanks for the response though. I searched it as well, and there is no api as of now that returns the bookmarks list.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not currently possible. The best I've seen is launching a page in mobile Safari with instructions on how to manually add the bookmark, or telling the user to add it on desktop Safari and sync the bookmark back to the iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

This is not currently possible. If it's something you'd like to see, you should [file an enhancement request](http://bugreporter.apple.com) with Apple.