# Add safari bookmark from iPhone app

Tags: iphone, objective-c, xcode, safari, bookmarks

I'd like to have my application be able to add bookmarks to safari programmatically, is this possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Not really possible : there's no API for that (and you can understand it from user perspective....).

An answer here confirms it :

[Add bookmark to Safari on iPhone when an application is installed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439213/add-bookmark-to-safari-on-iphone-when-an-application-is-installed/439231#439231)

Comment: ok, pretty much though it would be the case because of the user.

Answer (score -1):

You can't add a bookmark in Safari itself, but you can add an icon on the user's Home screen that bookmarks an arbitrary URL:

[User Experience Coding How-To's for Safari on iPhone](http://developer.apple.com/safari/library/codinghowtos/Mobile/UserExperience/index.html#GENERAL-CREATE_A_HOME_SCREEN_ICON_FOR_MY_WEBSITE_OR_WEB_APPLICATION)