# Generate home screen bookmarks from app (iOS)

Tags: ios, url, bookmarks

I'm adding URL schemes to my app and was wondering if its possible to generate and add bookmarks to the users home screen? I don't want a safari bookmark, I want a **home screen bookmark** and this might be possible by generating some HTML from within my app and pushing the HTML to safari. The HTML would contain visual cues to the user how to add the bookmark, maybe using one of the open source widgets available that do this, but like I said, creatin this HTML page within the app with a user custom URL embedded.

I'm still not sure on all the details of getting this to work, and whether safari would add a link on a page to home screen or only the link of the current page? I know in safari the user had to manually add the bookmark so I assume at least a system prompt would be involved which is fine. If this isn't possible, what would be the easiest method for a user to create a home screen bookmark if my app supplied them the URL?

Comment: [your question has been asked and answered before](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407330/add-safari-bookmark-from-iphone-app)

Comment: That question is different. I don't want to add a bookmark to safari. I want to add a home screen bookmark/icon

Answer (score 1):

There is currently no API to allow this type of functionality.  You can attempt it in a hack: [How could I create a shortcut on desktop in iOS through an app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7577889/how-could-i-create-a-shortcut-on-desktop-in-ios-through-an-app) but probably not a great idea.

Comment: Yes you should be able to open a page in safari and the user can manually add a home screen shortcut.