# How to implement bookmark feature by using WKWebview?

Tags: ios, swift, mobility

I would like to design a custom **WebView** component with the help of Apple WKWebView for in- app browsing, but couldn't get any idea how to implement bookmark feature(similar to safari). Any suggestions are welcome. Thanks in advance.

Comment: I think you can keep track of url and save them in your database.

Comment: This could help you : https://xcode4all.wordpress.com/2011/05/25/web-browser-or-how-to-use-the-uiwebview-part-33/

Comment: Thanks. So we should choose NSUserDefaults or CoreData to do this.

Comment: @AtWork, is there any way to add these bookmarks to safari bookmarks list?.

Comment: @srinu I don't think so. Check this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407330/add-safari-bookmark-from-iphone-app)