# Access User Bookmarks iPhone?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, ipad, bookmarks

From iOS 6 and later, it is possible to access the users bookmarks? Or would I have to create my own implementation?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't think this is possible. There's an old question for this here: [Add bookmark to Safari on iPhone when an application is installed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439213/add-bookmark-to-safari-on-iphone-when-an-application-is-installed/439231#439231)