# how to get all bookmarks from my app

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c

I am developing one application on iPhone and I required to find all bookmark that created in Device. I searched on Google and find [Add bookmark to Safari on iPhone when an application is installed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/439213/add-bookmark-to-safari-on-iphone-when-an-application-is-installed/439231#439231) and [Add safari bookmark from iPhone app](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2407330/add-safari-bookmark-from-iphone-app) is it Not Possible?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure this required a new question... no, it's still not possible to query bookmarks in Safari from a third party app.

Comment: Thanks for your replay, i asked this question because, other question are asked in the year 2009,2010.

Comment: @SAMIRRATHOD in the iOS world little has changed since 2009 in terms of security. You can't access other apps data form third party apps as well

Comment: @SergiusGee, any new api's for fetching the list of bookmarks?

Comment: Check out the SafariServices framework. That's where the "add to reading list" functionality is, so you'd expect to see reading/editing bookmarks in there too (if it exists, which it doesn't).